# How do you reverse log, square root, and Ln data transformations?

Tags: data-transformation, spss, descriptive-statistics, back-transformation

If you have transformed your data, is it true that when reporting results, such as descriptive statistics (e.g. mean, median, range, variance, standard deviation etc.), you need to revert the data back its original form?

If so, how would you go about doing this for log, square root, and Ln transformations?

Comment: Why did you do the transformation in the first place?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the welcome. I was having trouble performing a linear regression with my data in its original form (Sig. above 0.05). After further research online, I had an idea that one of the potential problems was heteroscedasticity, which could be possibly rectified by transforming the data for the dependent variable. I did so 3 times, via SQRT, Log, and Ln, and can now perform a linear regression using the variables (Sig. below 0.05 for all 3).

Comment: The inverse of $\log$ to base $a$ ($t=\log_a(y)$) is $y=a^t$, and keep in mind that $\ln$ is just $\log_e$. The inverse of $t=\sqrt{y}$ is $y=t^2$. To calculate quantiles (like medians), you can directly back-transform the values on the transformed scale but you can't do the same thing with means. standard deviations, or standard errors. I don't think I have ever been in a situation where I was undecided between a square root and a log transformation; usually which one would be best to use is fairly clear before I even have data (though more often I'd tend to do something other than transform)

Comment: Thank you for the help Glen. Is it possible to back-transform means, standard deviations, or standard errors?